# Apache Kafka Metrics Using Spring Boot

Tags: java, apache-kafka, monitoring, metrics, kafka-topic

I am new to Apache Kafka, I am trying to understand how can I monitor kafka brokers, consumers and producers and topics. I am looking for metrics and how can I expose Rest apis to get all these metrics as I have to display them on the UI. And how does JMX help to acheive this(or it does not?)

Comment: Are you using Spring boot ?

Answer (score 0):

some of the tool you can use to monitor Kafka is

- KafkaTool: http://www.kafkatool.com/
- Kafdrop3: https://github.com/obsidiandynamics/kafdrop